# Select multiple rows from different tables into one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using Postgresql with sqlalchemy ORM

I'm trying to use a sub-query to return an array of classes in a query.

```
subquery1 = session.query(Coupon).filter(Coupon.date > today)
subquery2 = session.query(Coupon).filter(Coupon.rate > 5)
result = session.query(User,func.array(subquery1.label("active")),
                   func.array(subquery1.label("expensive")))
```

this throws an error

> (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery must return only one column

When I only query the id from the subquery1 and 2 `session.query(Coupon.id)` it works fine and returns a list of ids that can be accessed with result[1] and result[2] which is exactly what I want except that I need the full class with all its attributes not just the attributes.

The current result is something like

```
[(<User object at 0x000001E88378F2E0>, [5,3], [])]
```

and I want it to be like this

```
[(<User object at 0x000001E88378F2E0>, [<Coupon object at 0x000001E88378F2E0>,<Coupon object at 0x000001E88378F2E0>], [])]
```

I also like to do it in 1 query instead of 3

The class `Coupon` and `User` are joined by a 3rd table that contains user_id and coupon_id but that is not relevant